# Can't import bundled file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs, jspm, es6-module-loader

I'm doing this in my application

```
System.import('lib/bootstrap.js').then(m => {
   this.socket = m.io("http://localhost:3000");
})
```

This is `bootstrap.js`

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
export { io };
```

I created a bundle via `jspm bundle lib/bootstrap.js outfile.js`.

When I try to `System.import('outfile.js')` the resolved Promise `m` is only an empty Object.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
System.import('outfile.js').then(m => {
   this.socket = m.io("http://localhost:3000");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to import the bundled file. What you need to do is inject the bundle configuration to your **config.js** file. For example adding `jspm bundle lib/bootstrap bootstrap-bundle.js --inject` will add

```
"bundles": {
    "bootstrap-bundle": [
    "socket.io-client.js",
    "lib/bootstrap.js"
  ]
}
```

to your config.js file. Then you just need to import your file as usual:

```
System.import('lib/bootstrap.js').then(m => {
   this.socket = m.io("http://localhost:3000");
})
```

See the [documentation here](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/blob/master/docs/production-workflows.md#creating-a-bundle).

Comment: What good for is the bundle then if I still load lib/bootstrap.js after bundling? Ideally I would like to load only system.Js and then one more file.

Comment: You don't load just the file. You load all the bundle. The thing is that jspm is smart enough to load the bundle for the file that you are asking for. For instance, in your example, you will load the bundle with 2 dependencies. If you do not use bundling you will need to load them in separate (i.e two requests to the server).